# If walking across the street unlawfully is jaywalking, is it safe to say biking across the street is jaybiking?

Tags: word-choice

Can the prefix "jay-" be used with any verb form so long as it represents crossing a street illegally?

For example, I went to NYC the past week for vacation, and noticed so many people, and bikers, especially bikers, crossing the street whenever they felt like it, red light or not, crosswalk or not.

Is it then okay to say they were "jaybiking"? Or is jaywalking just a loose term for any act of crossing the street unlawfully?

Comment: Have you bothered to check in any dictionary?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Considering it only appears on UrbanDictionary through a Google search, could I use jay- action verb in anything I write? Should jaywalking be used for all instances of crossing, or can I have specific verbs (jayrunning, jayboating, jaybiking, etc.)

Comment: you could say any of those and probably be understood, but only because the *jay-* prefix is rare. constructing words from rare prefixes like this is *relatively* common in english, but most people wouldn't consider them "real" words. jaywalking is a word, the others are constructions where you may or may not be understood. also, when writing a constructed word like people often use a hyphen to show it's a construction: *jay-biking*.

Comment: You can coin any word you like. Whether the coin becomes currency depends on whether others use it. *Jaybike* will be understood.

Comment: Jaywalking is a loose enough term to cover this; however, I believe that in most northeastern States, a bicycle with a mounted rider is a *vehicle* and is therefore subject to the same traffic laws as vehicles, unless a specific exception is made for them in the law; they are not subject to *pedestrian* law unless the rider has dismounted.

Comment: There is not (yet) a prefix _jay-_. There is only the American word _jaywalking_ (both the word and the concept little known in the UK). As Drew says, you can coin the word if you like.

Comment: The ctc don't seem to use it: 'cycling dangerously, carelessly, inconsiderately; pavement cycling ...'. It really depends on what impression you wish to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the American Heritage dictionary, a "jay" was an inexperienced person.  "Jaywalking" is a compound word, indicating that this is walking done by an inexperienced person.

I see no reason why you couldn't coin a new term as a compound word.

Comment: A person who is walking yet is inexperienced in walking... wow, that's a new one! Walk-ception!

Comment: @Zoe: It seems the term "jaywalker" originated as a sort of shaming campaign towards people who cross the street in front of cars.  It was part of introducing the notion that a road is primarily for automobiles.  The inexperience in this case would be in sharing the road with automobiles.

Comment: Cool. Though, I don't see jaybiking being conjured since *biking* is associated to either mountain biking or motorbikes. *Jaycycling* would be better when refering to the everyday commuter. There are so many new compound words I could come up with! Jayparking, jaysinging, jayeating, jayshopping... Okay okay, I will stop.

Comment: @Zoe I don't think _biking_ is limited the way you describe. Around here, people _bike_ to work, they don't _cycle_ to work.

Answer (score 0):

Sister site https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=jay does not seem to have any references to jay biking.

There is an [Idaho-Style Stop Law](http://www.sfbike.org/news/idaho-style-stop-law/), through which a bicycle may treat a stop sign as a yield sign. There are a handfew of blogs that discuss the [ethics of Idaho stop-style jaybiking](http://www.thewashcycle.com/2012/08/ethics-of-red-light-running.html).

Jaybiking seems to be a neologism that cropped up in some major metro areas (DC, SF). It may catch on; however, both blogs are from 2012 and it seems doubtful. Jayrunning or jayboating seem even more of a stretch.

Comment: 'There is an Idaho-Style Stop Law, through which a bicycle may treat a stop sign as a yield sign.' And some people say British syntax is too convoluted!

Comment: Edwin, that is a rule up with which I shall not put. (No, I don't believe Churchill said that, either.)